# Cortex M7 abnormal instruction-fetch behavior

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, cortex-m

I am a MCU digital IC designer. In our MCU design, we used Cortex-M7 to control our system. A random problem occurs during my simulation.

The LD file defined the RAM/CODE region(0x2801000~0x28030000), but M7 fetched instruction from 0x2800_fxxx sometimes. The memory from 0x2800_0000 to 0x2800_ffff is reserved,so it is not initiated at the start of simulation. Once M7 fetched instruction from 0x2800_fxxx, R-channel would get 64'hXXXX_XXXX, then M7's behavior is unpredictable.

We had reviewed our c-code, there is not operation to load from  0x2800_0000 to 0x2800_ffff region. So I wonder why M7 can initiate a instruction-fetch transaction from  0x2800_fxxx.

Comment: c code you mean machine code?

Comment: The Cortex-M7 has branch prediction and caching.  There are also DMA peripherals on some devices.  Are you sure your CPU is the bus master accessing this address?  Also, your simulator can be in error.  You should be able to log what instruction was causing the access.  It is very difficult for anyone to know as 'simulation' is a very abstract term.  Is this an HDL simulator (verilator, xsim, cadence, etc), is it a CPU simulation (qemu).  This is a hallmark of a bad question.  You assume that people know these details.

Comment: Sorry about my confusing description. 'simulation' I mentioned is a HDL simulator(VCS). During my HDL simulation, other BUS master like DMA is not enabled, and the fetch behavior is initiated by M7. Can you introduce some methods to log instructions? The current only debug way is to trace the rtl code from verdi, and it is hard to locate the root cause.

Comment: you said you were an mcu ic designer but you said you were looking at the c code.  An ic designer would be looking at the instructions being fetched and try to correlate the instructions (machine code) to the issue at hand, working by yourself or with a verification engineer who would/could associate the machine code to human readable assembly language to the C that created it through the compiler.

Comment: this could be as simple as the first stack access on a function call.  depending on what you have you may or may not have access to the arm core where you can dig in deeper, but in any case what did the bus transfers leading up to this event show (instructions being fetched, etc)(is this a data transfer or a fetch?)

Comment: have you narrowed the code sequences down to those that may be causing these cycles, be it prefetches, etc.   I think the m7 has caches, those are off yes or on.   You have basically provided zero information.

Comment: burn the candle from both ends, dig into the rtl based on the code running now and then alternate with modifying the code (or having the software engineer) to create different situations.  with branch prediction you can change the alignment of the code and sometimes that is enough to move, change or defeat the branch prediction (or just turn it off).

Comment: thanks for your reply. As mentioned above, M7 fetched instruction from the wrong address, and the only way to make M7 to perform such behaviors is the machine code. I try to initiate those piece of memory, then M7 can work properly. Although it still fetch instructions from the wrong address(0x00000000 received from AXI R channel), it has no impact on CPU, M7 works properly. In my HDL sim, the cache and TCM is not enabled and I tried to modify the compile-option of arm-gcc(from -01 to -O2), the abnormal behavior is disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I traced the Verilog code of M7 and checked the waveform. It was found that the address offset given by the BTAC module in M7 was negative, which caused an error in the predicted address of the branch. I received the wrong address prefetching instruction. I found that this situation occurs whenever BTAC records an address offset that exceeds 4K. After disabling the BTAC function, the code runs normally. I'm not sure if this is related to software compilation. I raised a case and asked ARM, but they haven't replied yet

Comment: I also raised a case about this issue to arm. According to their reply, this problem is caused by a feature named Speculative Access. You can reference the chapter 4 of m7 iim.